# Value '[X]' cannot be converted from Text to core.apexpages.el.adapters.metadata.VFSObjectELAdapter

Tags: visualforce, error, controller-extension, tasks, method

Faced with problem when saving the Task (Log a Call) record.
This error shows up below field Subject on edit layout.
My save Method is:

```
    Public PageReference saveRecord() {
    Task ts = new Task(); //Creating new record
    ts.Status = 'Completed';
    ts.OwnerId = UserId; //UserId my variable (IS NOT Null)
    ts.Priority = Task.Priority;
    ts.Communication_Type__c = Task.Communication_Type__c;
    ts.Subject = Task.Subject; //Just trying to set the field Subjectwith the value from my VF page
    insert Task;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help.

On the Task object there was a workflow rule that updates another field on the task object with Value: Text(Task.Subject__c). As the error said that the value can not be converted from text.

Comment: Can you please [edit] this answer with more detail? It's hard for anyone down the road who has this issue to learn from your mistake if your answer is unclear. Don't forget to accept it as correct, too!

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be same issue as posted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096AAIAY) in the Developer Forums, you may want to check that the object is properly instantiated and that the mapping param name from VF page is correct.

It should be

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Task.Subject}"></apex:inputField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a record named `Task`, it looks like you are trying to assign an `SObjectField` as a field value.

```
Schema.SObjectField subject = Schema.Task.Subject;
ts.Subject = subject; 
// same as
ts.Subject = Task.Subject;
```

If you do have a variable named `Task`, I would recommend renaming it to avoid confusion.

Also, it does not look like you really need to override the save method, but you can probably at least simplify to:

```
final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    this.controller = controller;
}
public PageReference save()
{
    insert controller.getRecord();
    // error handling recommended
    return null;
}
```